# Creating a closed parent-child network structure

Tags: network

I am new to this forum, and I am hoping that there is a mathematical solution to this situation. I am trying to form a network structure of parent and children nodes, but with some conditions. Following is a description:

Assume a finite number of nodes (Let's say 50 or take any finite one number. In an application of this structure, the real number might be very high). Now a closed structure of these nodes is to be constructed such that

1. Every node always has a single parent (there can be multiple parents in the network)
2. Every node always has a minimum of one child, there is no limit to the maximum number of children. In short, every node is a parent to atleast one node. If not every node, then a maximum number of nodes have atleast one child.

[Here is an example of a decentralized network.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s27NW.png) But it is an open network with end nodes without children, whereas I am looking at possibly a closed network with minimum or zero "childless" nodes.

Can such a structure exist? Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a triangle with vertices $a,b,c$. Say $a$ is a parent of $b$ which is a parent of $c$ which is a parent of $a$. Does that work for your definition of "parent" and "closed"?

Comment: I'm not sure that even the notions of "parent" and "child" are compatible with the closed structure. In binary trees, for instance, these terms make sense after specifying a choice of *root*, because there is only one path to each vertex from the root. If the graph is not a tree, there may be loops which prevent this interpretation. [EDIT: such as the situation Jake describes.]

Comment: Welcome to mathSE. Could you insert details into your question so that it's a perfectly well-defined mathematical question? I'm worried that you left out the definitions of several key concepts and didn't try to frame your question in a fully mathematical way.

Comment: Jake, it definitely works for a small number of nodes, like you described for 3 vertices, yes. But for a larger number of nodes, where there is a possibility to have more than one children for every node, this approach doesn't seem to  make justice.

Comment: Eric, the definition of parent and child are definitely visually easy to interpret in binary trees, but assuming that I can have any node as my child, except for siblings and immediate parent, the structure can have loops and still follow the parent & child notions.

Comment: 6005, I understand and apologise that my question is not framed in a fully mathematical way. But I am afraid that I am not a mathematics person, I come from the creative field, and hence unaware of the correct mathematical terms for this. But I hope I could explain further if there is anything specific that I couldn't make clear in my description?